# Unhide "Likes" on Facebook

Tags: facebook

Accidentally I hid the "Likes" on Facebook. All "Likes" disappeared. Does anyone know how to unhide them? Couldn't find anything on settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Click on your name on the Facebook bar at the top of the page.
2. Move your mouse over where it says **More** on the menu bar to the right of your profile photo. This will show a dropdown list of sections.
3. Click **Manage Sections**.
4. A new Manage Sections popup window will appear on the page. Click the checkbox to the left of where it says **Likes** to unhide it.
5. You can optionally drag the Likes menu entry up or down to reorder it.
6. Click the **Save** button to save the changes.